# Automate relinking Access tables to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have an Access program as a FE and a SQL Server as backend database. When I update my Access program, I made an ACCDE file and send it for my clients.

Unfortunately, I should remote to my clients PC and relink the new updated Access file to the SQL Server manually by making a DSN file.It is very frustrating and time consuming. Someone offered me the following code for relinking tables but it is applicable to Access database.

Now I want to automate this process. I want any user to be able to relink the new updated Access to the database in SQL Server by pressing a button in splash screen.

In the code in the article how can I specify the location of a SQL Server database in the server?

I can put and save the connection path in a table in BE database (in any different company) and recall it in the code. But I don't know how and where I should use it.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBSWQ.png)

Comment: There are numerous examples on how to achieve this. Bing/google on the keywords to find these.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are part of their same network? Or on their same network?

Then you take your accDB. Use the linked table manager, and link to the production "live" instance of sql server. No code is required for this re-link process.

In ALL CASES - and I repeat in ALL CASES you want to use a FILE dsn when you link. This is because access automatic converts a FILE DSN to what we call a DSN-LESS connection. Once you link, then you create the accDE, and you are now free to deploy this front end accDE to any and all computers on that network. There is no client side DSN setup or configuration when you use  FILE dsn in access.

Now, there is the case when you are NOT on site, and you can't pre-link the accDB (that you going to THEN turn into a accDE - right!!!).

Even when I am off-site, I often have a VPN to that customer site. And thus again, I can use the linked table manage to re-link the tables - and ZERO VBA code is required. Once linked to that sql server (using Access UI + linked table manager), then I am free to create the accDE - and that accDE can now be distributed to ANY work station on that network, and no DSN or any kind of configuration is required!

However, there are a number of cases in which you may well be off-site and can NOT be part of their network. In that case, then yes, you do need + want some re-link code on startup.

Becuase you going to provide a WHOLE NEW front end - one that will over-write their existing front end? Then what I do is adopt a standard in which the FE on each computer ALSO has a simple link.txt file placed in the SAME location. Now, on startup it is a simple matter to read that text file, and check a linked table to see if they are the same - if they are not, then we run your sample re-link code based on the link information we saved in that text file. Thus, you are free to update and provide the great next new version of your software, and on startup we read in that simple text file to get the server information. If that information does not match a linked table (I just grab the first linked table), then we simply run the VBA re-link routines you have with the information from that text file. In some cases, I will and have used a simple table in the FE with one row - and you can thus set/change the server information that way right before you deploy. So in place of that simple text file, you have a simple one row table in the FE that holds this information. This of course requires to "remember" to change/update that one row table record with the customers sql server information. Once again, the process on startup is much the same - you check that information, and if the first linked table is different, then you run the re-link VBA code on startup. Thus, that re-link code will only ever run one time.

So, if you are on-site and on the same network? Then you don't need any VBA re-link code, you can just use the built in linked table manager and re-link the tables. AS LONG AS YOU use a FILE dsn, then no workstation configuration is or will be required, since by default and automatic Access converts a FILE dsn into a dsn-less one for you - all without any VBA code. Once you re-linked this way, then create the accDE, and then distribute that to any and all workstations on that network.

In effect, you ONLY need some VBA re-link code if you are going to provide that site with a new updated accDE - and you can't be on or part of that network to re-link the tables before creating that accDE.

Comment: Dear Mr.Kallal,
I certainly agree with you that I can save the information of server and network path in a one row table. It is the best solution for me. And it is very convenient that I can amend the table data when the server path or information changed. But do you have any solution that I can get the information of tables(connection string) including server path, name and other info by a vba code?

Comment: There are truckloads of examples. just search for Access dsn link tables. Here is one such link and example: https://cloudydatablog.net/?p=118

Comment: this one also shows how to get the older/existing connection: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3591276/Manual-Table-Relinking.htm